# Get informations from a firebase collection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to read informations from a firebase collection  in react and i can only read one with this code. Can some help me?

This is my code that only return one element

```
async function(){   
  const docRef = doc(db, "transactions/yaounde/income/GWL5xaGgrSvmaYNXhSLx");
  const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
  if (docSnap.exists()) {
    console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
  } else {
    console.log(docSnap.data())
    console.log("No such document!");
  }
};
```

I have already tried to reduce the number on segment in the reference but it return undefined

Answer (score 0):

From the Firebase documentation on [reading multiple documents from a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection):

```
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "cities"));
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});
```